# Sending Active element from all clients to server

Tags: javascript, socket.io, collaborative-editing

Lets say i have a collaborative text-editor.

Collaborator A writing on a paragraph A.

Collaborator B writing on a paragraph B.

Collaborator C writing on a paragraph C.

I want to send active element of A,B,C (element focused) to server and emit it to all client.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

There is much information about this on the internet.

You can try to complete a tutorial of chat with socket.io:
**http://socket.io/get-started/chat/**

Here another project:
**https://github.com/laktek/realie**

Comment: I have reffered to all those, but my query is not implemented in all those apps.